# regular expression for selecting ip addresses

Tags: windows, powershell, regex

Help me write a regular expression that selects rows that start at `192` and end with `2` or `002`?
I want to get a list of IP addresses, they can consist of `192.168.001.002`, `192.168.001.2`, `192.168.1.002` or `192.168.1.2` kinds, but I want to choose only according to my rule.

I did it this way:

```
(\d{3}\.)(\d{3}\.)(\d{1,3}\.)(\d{1,3})
```

but how to find the lines to start and end with certain digits?

update

```
(\d{3}\.)(\d{3}\.)(\d{1,3}\.)([02]{1,3})
```

It works well, but selects an unnecessary string `192.168.027.021`

Comment: added, but I'm not strong in regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want IP begin with `192`, add it at the beginning of the regex:

```
192\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.[02]{1,3}
```

You want it ends with `002` or `2`, the use:

```
192\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.(00)?2
```

where `(00)?` means optional two zeros.

Comment: Minor warning. Many systems interpreted 001 as an octed. So you have 001 though 007, but 008 does not exits. Instead it is 011 (nine in octal). So be rcareful where you use IP padded to look nice.

Answer (score 1):

**Summarizing and clarify the question and goals:**

- Goal: get a list of IP addresses which start with `192` and end with `2` or `002`
- Consisting of: `192.168.001.002`, `192.168.001.2`, `192.168.1.002` or
  `192.168.1.2`
- Tried:  `(\d{3}\.)(\d{3}\.)(\d{1,3}\.)(\d{1,3})`
- Updated: `(\d{3}\.)(\d{3}\.)(\d{1,3}\.)([02]{1,3})` -- Works, but selects an unnecessary string `192.168.027.021`

**Probably what you want is:**

- `grep -P "\b\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.[02]{1,3}\b" ip.txt`
- Select-String `"\b\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.[02]{1,3}\b" ip.txt`
- (Get-Content ip.txt) `-match "\b\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.[02]{1,3}\b"`

If you really want just '192' as the first octet, then make that a literal:

`Select-String "\b192\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.[02]{1,3}\b" ip.txt`

If you just want IP-patterns that end with only 0 or 2 in the last octet these will work too (the 3 patterns are the same):

- `grep -P "\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}[02]{1,3}\b" ip.txt`
- Select-String `"\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}[02]{1,3}\b" ip.txt`
- (Get-Content ip.txt) `-match "\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}[02]{1,3}\b"`

One to three digits then a `.`, three times, then 1-3 `0` or `2` characters, with a 'word' break before & after.

It depends some on what Regex tool you are using but I'll test with `grep -P` (PCRE/perl compatible) or PowerShell/.Net which is quite similar.

Your first Regex:  `(\d{3}\.)(\d{3}\.)(\d{1,3}\.)(\d{1,3})` says:

1. Find 3 digits and a literal `.` (Dot)
2. Followed by: 3 digits and a literal `.` (Dot)
3. Followed by: 1 to 3 digits and a literal `.` (Dot)
4. Followed by: 1 to 3 digits

The parens are mostly unnecessary unless you are going to quantify groups or use them in a replace or backreference.

It says nothing about any of this having to be "at the beginning or at the end of the string/line -- probably Ok, but if these are embedded in a text it might not be an accurate assumption.

You 2nd attempt `(\d{3}\.)(\d{3}\.)(\d{1,3}\.)([02]{1,3})` is similar except for the 4th part `([02]{1,3})` which says:

- Find a `0` or a `2` one to three times.

... so yes it will match when the end is `021` -- that's `02` and their is nothing to say "must be at end or line or next character can't be a digit (that isn't a `0` or `2`).

You need to "anchor" you regex for that -- anchor it to the end of the line, to literal text, or to a "word break" etc.

Simplest and perhaps most general is bhe "word break" anchor: \b

It's a zero-width assertion (matches no actual characters but asserts/requires something to be true, the transition from 'word characters' to non-word characters.)

- Yours: `grep -P "(\d{3}\.)(\d{3}\.)(\d{1,3}\.)([02]{1,3})\b" ip.txt`
- Fixed: `grep -P "\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.[02]{1,3}\b" ip.txt`
- Simplified: `grep -P "\b\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.[02]{1,3}\b" ip.txt`

Comment: OP wants to select only IPs that begin with `192`

Comment: @toto Yes, that seemed to be the case, but my response was kept to the examples he used which didn't confirm that "192" only requirement..
I'll add a reference to that.